# Error : The type com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedI cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, openfire

While building a OpenFire project in Eclipse im getting the following error shown at the starting of my class file within the comments although i have added all the required updated jar files

How to solve this!

The type com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedI cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the following build error: "the type {---} cannot be resolved. it is indirectly referenced from required .class files"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464592/getting-the-following-build-error-the-type-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind)

Comment: i have already done with buildpath still im facing this error @LisaMM

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is in “ROME” dependency, which generates RSS feed. For Maven, include below dependency in pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```